# Django error with get_absolute_url

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views, django-urls

I am working of django ecommerce project. Adding any other url to my html page single.html (displays products by particular baker or manufacturer) gives Error HTTP404. 
So on this single.html page products are displayed. I have added add to cart button. When I don't mention the link of add_to_cart in button tag it displays the page and when I mention it given HTTP404 error

views.py for showing the manufacturer (baker in my case)

```
def BakerDetail(request, slug):
try:
    baker = Baker.objects.get(slug=slug)
    products = Product.objects.filter(baker=baker)
    context = {
    'baker': baker,
    'products': products
    }
    template = 'bakers/single.html'
    return render(request, template, context)
except:
    raise Http404
```

single.html

```
<table class='table'>
<thead>
<th></th>
<th>Products</th>
</thead>
<tbody>
{% for items in products %} 
<tr>
<td></td>
<td>
<a href="{{ items }}">
{{ items }}</a>
{{ items.price }}
<button class="btn btn-primary" href="{% url 'add_to_cart' %}">Add To Cart</button>
</td>
<td></td>
</tr>
{% endfor %}
</tbody>
</table>
```

view for add_to_cart

```
def Add_To_Cart(request, slug):
request.session.set_expiry(120000)
try:
    the_id = request.session['cart_id']
except:
    new_cart = Cart()
    new_cart.save()
    request.session['cart_id'] = new_cart.id
    the_id = new_cart.id

cart = Cart.objects.get(id=the_id)

try:
    product = Product.objects.get(slug=slug)
except Product.DoesNotExist:
    pass
except:
    pass
```

urls.py

```
url(r'^cart/(?P<slug>[\w-]+)/$', views.Add_To_Cart, name='add_to_cart'),
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's not answering your questions but these are bugging me ! More seriously these small details add up and will make your work harder.

`def BakerDetail(...)` => `def baker_detail(...)`

`def Add_To_Cart(...)` => `def add_to_car(...)`

`try: baker = Baker.objects.get(slug=slug) ... except ...` => `baker = get_object_or_404(Baker, slug=slug)`
see: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/http/shortcuts/#get-object-or-404

`{% for items in products %}` => `{% for item in products %}`

---

Just to be clear your view could look like this (the behaviour is the same):

```
def baker_detail(request, slug):
    baker = get_object_or_404(Baker, slug=slug)
    products = Product.objects.filter(baker=baker)
    return render(request, 'bakers/single.html', {
        'baker': baker,
        'products': products
    })
```

Comment: Thank you @Francois. It worked. and I will make the changes as you said.

Answer (score 2):

You need to pass the slug into the `url` tag, to tell it which element you want to add.

```
{% url 'add_to_cart' slug=items.slug %}
```

(Note it would be clearer if you called the variable "item", not "items").